# dynamic price in windows store application in app purchase

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, in-app-purchase

I want to sell some product in my application (windows 8 store app) and the problem is I retrieve the prices from server and it can change time to time ,can I change the xml file that represents prices in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your controls described in XAML file to data structure in C# or VB.NET code. Read about data binding.

Some links: [data binding in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), [in Windows Store Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320.aspx), [MVVM pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. No, there is (not yet) any API to interact with your catalog of durable in-app purchases. What you can do instead, however, is to create multiple entries for different prices. For example:

1. Id=1 LevelOne $1.00
2. Id=2 LevelOne $2.00

If you detect that the variables are correct to sell for the lower price you can show Id=1 and if you determine the higher price then Id=2. You are "technically' selling two different "Level One" products but there's no reason your user needs to know that.

Answer (score 0):

I know the solution now,the XML file in Sample is just for simulating purchase and it won't do anything for you in real Store,when you want to submit your application in Windows Store you define products and prices there and it is static ,I recommend you to start submitting a dummy project in windows store then you can develop with a perfect view .